# conda problem on rp3: "Could not find some dependencies for <package>: blas * openblas"

Tags: raspberry-pi3, conda

After updating my RP3 to kernel release/version `4.14.52-v7+/#1123`, trying to install or update packages such as pandas, numpy, etc. with `conda` (arm71, v3.16.0) causes an error:

```
Error: Could not find some dependencies for <package>: blas * openblas
```

Installing packages with `pip` still works fine.

Comment: I have the same problem after installing Miniconda 3. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The best option for you will be to use [berryconda](https://github.com/jjhelmus/berryconda), as standard conda channels lack the support of ARM-based builds

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approach to my understanding.
I'm not 100% that it resolves your issue, so any feedback is of interest.

(Some info were found here: [Scientific Python for Raspberry Pi](https://geoffboeing.com/2016/03/scientific-python-raspberry-pi/))

---

I have found that some packages are available using `apt-get` :

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-pandas python-h5py
```

I realize that it is not strictly conda usage but it can do the trick.

---

Otherwise, you can use the follwing commands (here exmaple is given with scipy).
Please be aware that you might face compatibility issues between packages or python versions.
Some packages might not be available for ARM

```
anaconda search -t conda scipy
```

This gives you something like:

```
Using binstar api site https://api.anaconda.org
Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
Packages:
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms      
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
     Alges/scipy               |   0.19.1 | conda           | linux-64, win-64
                                          : Scientific Library for Python
     BioBuilds/scipy           |    1.0.0 | conda           | linux-ppc64le  
... some lines removed ... here is a result with a grep on 'arm'
     RaspberryPi/scipy         |   0.13.2 | conda           | linux-armv6l   
     alorenzo175/scipy         |   0.18.0 | conda           | linux-armv7l   
     compass/scipy             |   0.19.0 | conda           | linux-armv7l   
     poppy-project/scipy       |   0.17.0 | conda           | linux-armv7l   
     rpi/scipy                 |    1.0.0 | conda           | linux-armv6l, linux-armv7l
```

then you can do this:

```
anaconda show rpi/scipy
```

which gives:

```
Using binstar api site https://api.anaconda.org
Name:    scipy
Summary: Scientific Library for Python
Access:  public
Package Types:  conda
Versions:
   + 0.18.1
   + 0.19.0
   + 0.19.1
   + 1.0.0

To install this package with conda run:
     conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/rpi scipy
```

Then all you have to do is execute the said command:

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/rpi scipy

Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: .
Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications.
Generating hint: 
[      COMPLETE      ]|#################################################################################################################################################################################################################| 100%


Hint: the following packages conflict with each other:
  - scipy
  - python 3.4*

Use 'conda info scipy' etc. to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Printing some infos:

```
conda info scipy
Fetching package metadata: ....

scipy 0.16.0 np19py34_1
-----------------------
file name   : scipy-0.16.0-np19py34_1.tar.bz2
name        : scipy
version     : 0.16.0
build number: 1
build string: np19py34_1
channel     : defaults
size        : 24.4 MB
date        : 2015-08-20
license     : BSD
md5         : a1f8618171817de092b818a3739ef95c
installed environments:
dependencies:
    blas * openblas
    numpy 1.9*
    openblas 0.2.14
    python 3.4*

scipy 0.16.0 np19py27_1
-----------------------
file name   : scipy-0.16.0-np19py27_1.tar.bz2
name        : scipy
version     : 0.16.0
build number: 1
build string: np19py27_1
channel     : defaults
size        : 25.1 MB
date        : 2015-08-20
license     : BSD
md5         : bc3882c6770d1dc7e3e5495266002d56
installed environments:
dependencies:
    blas * openblas
    numpy 1.9*
    openblas 0.2.14
    python 2.7*
```

Comment: as of today, I ran all the commands from the link on my RPi3 running "Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)" and it went smoothly without any issue. thanks